# image size in pixels, from Photoshop to webpage

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I have this png image i created in photoshop, 64x64 pixels. I created a div on my webpage with height and width set to 64px and gave the div a 1px border. If i place the png inside the div, the image is larger than the div. Why is this if both the image and the size of the div are set to 64x64?

Comment: Can you include sufficient code to demonstrate the problem you're facing? Otherwise it may be difficult to identify the cause of this.

Comment: in some browsers, the width of the div is including the border width

Answer (score 0):

Apologies....

Through trial and error I discovered that it was in fact a browser issue. I had previously had the div a different size and I was using Chrome. Took me a while but I found out that Chrome uses cached version of a page (I'm using Xamp on localhost) and simply reloading the page wasn't updating the width and/or height of the div. It appears that it simply wasn't updating. Switching to Firefox solved my issue